# No suitable driver found for jdbc:sqlserver in Spring framework

Tags: java, sql-server, spring, jdbc

I'm working in IntelliJ Ultimate on a Spring based web application.  I have downloaded the necessary jar from Microsoft (https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=11774), and it is in my class path.

I have the following code in my web app:

```
    try {
         conn = DriverManager.getConnection(strSQLConnection, strSQLUserUpdates, strSQLPWUpdates);
    } catch (SQLException e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

When I run the web app (On a Tomcat 9.0.0.M8 server), I get a "No suitable driver found for jdbc:sqlserver" error in the Server log.

However, I run the exact same code outside the Spring framework, the connection is established without issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was missing the necessary datasource bean in my application context file.  Adding the following to my application context (-servlet.xml) fixed the issue:

```
<bean id="datasource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver"/>
</bean>
```

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that any of your dependencies isn't downloading your jdbc driver in other version (in case you use maven or gradle).

And second thought: if your dependency has scope provided for jdbc driver, add lib manually to tomcat/libs folder.